# Nvidia Properietary drivers stopped working after upgrade to kernel 5.15.0-52-generic In Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nvidia, kernel, display, 22.04

Not sure if anyone else is facing this issue, but the NVidia proprietary drivers just stopped working after updating.

Here's what I'm seeing:

nvidia-driver-515 - Black screen after boot
nvidia-driver-515-open - Black screen after login

Only the noveau drivers work, but they're awful for gaming (I'm getting 1 fps in Unigine Heaven).

And Ctrl+Alt+F1(F2, F3 etc) don't work either. I had to uninstall all nvidia* drivers from recovery mode to be able to login to the UI.

Comment: Did you try loading the older kernel from the Grub menu on startup?

Comment: Yeah, same problem there. Not sure why though. :(

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in the next kernel update. They broke something, and then fixed it. It's working now.